# TFS 2013 auto assign to myself

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

My question is, if it is possible in the TFS 2013 Scrum process template, to make a work item (task) on the scrum board, automatically assign to myself when moving it from "to do" to "in progress"? Should it be possible to add this in the process template on TFS?

We are using an on premise TFS 2013 environment.

I thought I have seen the configuration somewhere but I can't find it on the internet (maybe I am using the wrong search keywords).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to edit the process template for the Task Work Item Type Definition.

1. Use [`witadmin.exe exportwitd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx) to download the Task definition
2. Find the Transition from "To Do" to "In Progress" and change it like so:

   ```
   <TRANSITION from="To Do" to="In Progress">
     <ACTIONS>
       <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork" />
     </ACTIONS>
     <FIELDS>
       <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
         <COPY from="currentuser" />
       </FIELD>
     </FIELDS>
     <REASONS>
       <DEFAULTREASON value="Work started" />
     </REASONS>
   </TRANSITION>
   ```
3. Use `witadmin.exe importwitd` to re-import the Task definition.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will test this today in my environment.